# How do you use the Wall-nut first aid ability?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I don't see it in my plant list, and I have checked over and over again.  It's not there. What is the sun cost for it?

Answer (score 4):

First aid isn't a separate plant, it's the ability to replace damaged blocking plants (the question is for PvZ2, but it seems the behaviour is the same as in the first game).

From http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Wall-nut_First_Aid

> Wall-nut First Aid allows the player to plant new Wall-nuts, Tall-nuts
>   and Pumpkins on top of damaged plants of the same kind without having
>   to dig them up first.

Comment: I tried to do so in save our seed. I do not think it works.

Comment: @jimthio it does.  YOu have to plant the exact same type of nut to refresh it.  And also, fyi to the answerer, there are no pumpkins in pvz2, but the rest still applies.